# Child component not updating when state passed to it

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and am trying to make a master detail view.  I've made a sandbox example of what I'm trying to do. https://codesandbox.io/s/black-darkness-hp5eek
The issue is, the child component is not updating it's value.  I'm sure I'm doing something simple.
I can do a

```
console.log(props.dataItem);
```

in the details component and the object is being passed in correctly.  But the state in the details component is not displaying

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.

Comment: Your detail component has its own state rather than you passing the parent state down into it. If you want to use parent state, just pass it via props, together with the setter and call that setter in the detail component. No reason to copy parent state into a separate child state and play catch between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code sandbox, I realized you have a missing dependency in your `useEffect`.

This is your actual `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setDataItem(props.dataItem);
  }, []);
```

If you are trying to make the `useEffect` run only on first render, you need to leave empty the square brackets (`[]`). In your case, you want `setDataItem` to run every change on `dataItem`, so you need to put the variable inside the square brackets. You can see those warnings on your code sandbox; or, if you are using VS Code, you can use the "ESLint" extension.

Your `useEffect` after changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setDataItem(props.dataItem);
  }, [props.dataItem]);
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  For the sample code given I'd still recommend not duplicating state in the first place.  But this could be useful for future readers where the use case does call for locally duplicating state and being able to update that state when the prop changes.  (Though such use cases would likely have other considerations in their UX, like whether or not to overwrite the locally duplicated state with the new prop if that state has been meaningfully modified in the local component.)

Comment: You are right, he is using unnecessary useState and useEffect but i want to make clear for the new users, the uses of useEffect and the dependencies on square brackets. Your solution is correct, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what your `Details` component does:

```
function Details(props) {

  console.log(props.dataItem);

  const defaultItem = {
    company: "",
    ticker: "",
    stockPrice: ""
  };

  const [dataItem, setDataItem] = useState(defaultItem);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDataItem(props.dataItem);
  }, []);

  if (!dataItem) return;

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Details</h2>
      Name: {dataItem.company}
      <br />
      Ticker: {dataItem.ticker}
      <br />
      Stock Price: {dataItem.stockPrice}
    </>
  );
}
```

It accepts a `dataItem` prop, but then sets that value to its own internal state and then:

- Only ever uses that internal state
- Never updates that internal state

Why is it duplicating state at all?  If the goal is to rely on the prop, just use the prop:

```
function Details({ dataItem }) {
  if (!dataItem) return;
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Details</h2>
      Name: {dataItem.company}
      <br />
      Ticker: {dataItem.ticker}
      <br />
      Stock Price: {dataItem.stockPrice}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value to `dataItem` in `Details.js` only ONCE when you are rendering your component because you are setting it in `useEffect` with empty dependency array.

To fix that you can put `props.dataItem` in the dependency array but it's not a good solution for that.

you actually dont need that seperate state.

This is enough to make it work

```
function Details({ dataItem }) {
  if (!dataItem) return null;
  
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Details</h2>
      Name: {dataItem.company}
      <br />
      Ticker: {dataItem.ticker}
      <br />
      Stock Price: {dataItem.stockPrice}
    </>
  );
}
```

also you don't needed a `defaultItem` since you don't want to display anything without `dataItem`